# How to change the titlebar color of a window in a Qt/Qml application?

Tags: windows, qt, qt5.5

I would like to change the colour of the (top) border and the titlebar of the window of my application in Qt 5.5, but can't find any solution. I know I can create a frameless windows (but then resizing doesn't work) and style my own window, I can also change the background colour of the window, but the border colour. I think there is probably since most apps in Windows 10 are able to do this.

Comment: I have been done some further research and it seems there is not "official"  solution to this problem. Looking up I ran into this project https://github.com/deimos1877/BorderlessWindow which works fine (I have been able to build it and make it work). I modified the QWinWidget file (subclassing to QWindow). However this solution does not work for a Qml application and I am struggling to think about a way to make it work with a QtQuick application.